# Can't require laravel/passport with composer

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, composer-php

When I do `composer require laravel/passport`, I get

> Using version ^5.0 for laravel/passport ./composer.json has been
>   updated Loading composer repositories with package information
>   Updating dependencies (including require-dev) Your requirements could
>   not be resolved to an installable set of packages.
>
> Problem 1
>       - Installation request for laravel/passport ^5.0 -> satisfiable by laravel/passport[v5.0.0].
>       - Conclusion: remove laravel/framework v5.5.34
>       - Conclusion: don't install laravel/framework v5.5.34
>       - laravel/passport v5.0.0 requires illuminate/encryption ~5.6 -> satisfiable by illuminate/encryption[v5.6.0, v5.6.1, v5.6.2, v5.6.3].
>       - don't install illuminate/encryption v5.6.0|don't install laravel/framework v5.5.34
>       - don't install illuminate/encryption v5.6.1|don't install laravel/framework v5.5.34
>       - don't install illuminate/encryption v5.6.2|don't install laravel/framework v5.5.34
>       - don't install illuminate/encryption v5.6.3|don't install laravel/framework v5.5.34
>       - Installation request for laravel/framework (locked at v5.5.34, required as 5.5.*) -> satisfiable by laravel/framework[v5.5.34].
>
> Installation failed, reverting ./composer.json to its original
>   content.

I think this means that my version of `illuminate/encryption` is not compatible with this version of `laravel/passport`

Is that correct? What is the best way to resolve this? I can't even figure out how to see what version of `illuminate/encryption` I have. It doesn't show up in `composer show`.

Here is my composer.json

```
{
    "name": "laravel/laravel",
    "description": "The Laravel Framework.",
    "keywords": ["framework", "laravel"],
    "license": "MIT",
    "type": "project",
    "require": {
        "php": ">=7.0.0",
        "fideloper/proxy": "~3.3",
        "laravel/framework": "5.5.*",
        "laravel/tinker": "~1.0",
        "tymon/jwt-auth": "dev-develop"
    },
    "require-dev": {
        "filp/whoops": "~2.0",
        "fzaninotto/faker": "~1.4",
        "mockery/mockery": "~1.0",
        "phpunit/phpunit": "~6.0",
        "symfony/thanks": "^1.0"
    },
    "autoload": {
        "classmap": [
            "database/seeds",
            "database/factories"
        ],
        "psr-4": {
            "App\\": "app/"
        }
    },
    "autoload-dev": {
        "psr-4": {
            "Tests\\": "tests/"
        }
    },
    "extra": {
        "laravel": {
            "dont-discover": [
            ]
        }
    },
    "scripts": {
        "post-root-package-install": [
            "@php -r \"file_exists('.env') || copy('.env.example', '.env');\""
        ],
        "post-create-project-cmd": [
            "@php artisan key:generate"
        ],
        "post-autoload-dump": [
            "Illuminate\\Foundation\\ComposerScripts::postAutoloadDump",
            "@php artisan package:discover"
        ]
    },
    "config": {
        "preferred-install": "dist",
        "sort-packages": true,
        "optimize-autoloader": true
    }
}
```

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Passport 5.0 depends on version 5.6 of the `Illuminate` packages. I can see you have Laravel 5.5 installed, so either upgrade Laravel to 5.6, or use the 4.0 branch of Passport.

The `"require"` section of `composer.json` in the Passport repository has it all specified:

```
"require": {
    "php": ">=7.0",
    "firebase/php-jwt": "~3.0|~4.0|~5.0",
    "guzzlehttp/guzzle": "~6.0",
    "illuminate/auth": "~5.6",
    "illuminate/console": "~5.6",
    "illuminate/container": "~5.6",
    "illuminate/contracts": "~5.6",
    "illuminate/database": "~5.6",
    "illuminate/encryption": "~5.6",
    "illuminate/http": "~5.6",
    "illuminate/support": "~5.6",
    "league/oauth2-server": "^6.0",
    "phpseclib/phpseclib": "^2.0",
    "symfony/psr-http-message-bridge": "~1.0",
    "zendframework/zend-diactoros": "~1.0"
},
```

The `Illuminate` version numbers line up with the frameworks, so Laravel 5.6 would use Illuminate 5.6, 5.5 would use Illuminate 5.5, etc.

See: [Upgrade Guide - Upgrading To 5.6.0 From 5.5](https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/upgrade).

Comment: Is this as simple as changing the composer.json to Laravel 5.6 and doing `composer update`? Or is there more involved?

Comment: It's more involved than that, although the upgrade to 5.6 has been the easiest one yet, imo. Here's the complete [upgrade guide](https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/upgrade).

Answer (score 1):

I got this same issue I solved this using the following command

```
composer require laravel/passport -W
```

-W(--with-all-dependencies) allows upgrades, downgrades, and removals for packages currently locked to specific versions.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue I am using Laravel Framework 5.4

It got solved by using lower version of passport

`composer require laravel/passport "4.0.3"`